# How to avoid an exception using the ternary conditional operator (or other) without a try/except?

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement, exception, ternary-operator

Each of the Google review score elements (of which there are 20) on a page such as [this](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=chiropractors%2Bnew%20york%2Bny&rflfq=1&tbm=lcl&tbs=lf:1,lf_ui:2&oll=40.753684075373776,-73.98139879999997&ospn=0.009947864395265071,0.01613616943359375&oz=16&fll=40.75791015795404,-73.95807431040645&fspn=0.03978892801050904,0.064544677734375&fz=14&rlfi=hd:;si:&rlha=0):

[image]

is defined in XPath thus:

```
  //ol/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[i]/div/div[3]/div/a[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/span
```

For some reason, when I try fetch all 20 with the following XPath, only the review scores that are ***not*** 'No reviews' get returned:

```
In [20]: reviews = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//ol/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[position() >= 1 and position() <= 20]/div/div[3]/div/a[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/span")

In [21]: [i.text for i in reviews]

Out[21]: 
[u'20 reviews',
 u'4 reviews',
 u'4 reviews',
 u'15 reviews',
 u'2 reviews',
 u'7 reviews',
 u'3 reviews',
 u'14 reviews',
 u'2 reviews',
 u'4 reviews',
 u'3 reviews',
 u'30 reviews',
 u'6 reviews',
 u'3 reviews',
 u'2 reviews']
```

If I try to fetch these 'No reviews' elements individually, I get:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//ol/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[6]/div/div[3]/div/a[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/span"}
Stacktrace:
    at FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal_ (file:///var/folders/th/40phk7_13ng3_7zs1rg70plh0000gn/T/tmpoUEQvJ/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10299)
    at FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElement (file:///var/folders/th/40phk7_13ng3_7zs1rg70plh0000gn/T/tmpoUEQvJ/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10308)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h (file:///var/folders/th/40phk7_13ng3_7zs1rg70plh0000gn/T/tmpoUEQvJ/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12282)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_ (file:///var/folders/th/40phk7_13ng3_7zs1rg70plh0000gn/T/tmpoUEQvJ/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12287)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/< (file:///var/folders/th/40phk7_13ng3_7zs1rg70plh0000gn/T/tmpoUEQvJ/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12229)
```

I need a way to populate a list or dict with all 20 review scores in one go, while keeping track of their position in the 20 results, and populating a value of 0 every time 'No Reviews' is encountered. I tried using the ternary conditional operator, but I obviously I will get the NoSuchElementException each time a review score is 'No Reviews', before the statement gets to say `else 0`:

```
In [30]: mydict[6] = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//ol/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[6]/div/div[3]/div/a[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/span").text if driver.find_element_by_xpath("//ol/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[6]/div/div[3]/div/a[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/span").text else 0
```

How can I check for the non-presence or presence of the element in question without triggering an exception?

Comment: Why not use try/except? It's the perfect case for this.

Comment: The "for some reason" is that, as the error message indicates, the "No review" elements don't exist at the XPath location you're using.  Looking at the page, it looks like the ones with reviews have an extra div between the `a` tag and the `span` that the no-review ones don't have.  You could try refining your XPath to get both in one query (perhaps by using the `role="heading"` attribute that appears on some of the divs).  Otherwise you'll have to query for a higher-level element like the business header itself, then iterate over that and check for the presence of the review on each one.

Comment: @f.rodrigues Yes, that's what I am currently doing (in my Webdriver program), but it is very costly from a time point of view. Each try/except is taking anywhere between 5 and 10 seconds to process.

Comment: Can you show us an example of that code?